# form drop-down selection based input trigger in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

my form has drop-down form `invoice type` which has two value when user select **services** i want to hide from_date and to_date field from form, when user select **milestone** i want to hide upload_file input from form.

```html
<form id="raise-invoice-form-validation" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="field columns large-3">
        <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_invoice_type">Invoice type</label>
        <select name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_type]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_type"><option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="0">services</option>
<option value="1">milestones</option></select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="field columns large-3">
        <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_from_date">From date</label>
        <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker"  type="date" name="raise_invoice[from_date]" id="raise_invoice_from_date"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button>
      </div>

      <div class="field columns large-3">
        <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_to_date">To date</label>
        <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" name="raise_invoice[to_date]" id="raise_invoice_to_date"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button>
      </div>

      <input value="20" type="hidden" name="raise_invoice[payment_milestone_id]" id="raise_invoice_payment_milestone_id">

      <div class="field columns large-2">
        <label for="raise_invoice_upload_file">Upload file</label>
        <input type="file" name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_file]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_file">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="field columns large-3">
        <label for="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_for">Raised invoice for</label>
        <select name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_for]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_for"><option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="0">Performa Invoice</option>
<option value="1">Tax Invoice</option></select>

    <div class="actions text-center">
      <input type="submit" value="Raise invoice" class="button primary button-margin-top" data-disable-with="Raise invoice">
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I think you'll find that my answer does exactly what you require.

Comment: Drop-down select of invoice_type doesn't trigger inputs

Comment: @cssyphus Thats not what OP wanted. Please review your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply `change` function to check which `option` was selected and hide the relevant `divs` accordingly.

//hide on load
$('.from_date, .to_date').hide()
$('.upload_field').hide()

```
//watch the change
$(document).on('change', '#raise_invoice_raised_invoice_type', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '0') {
    $('.from_date, .to_date').hide()
    $('.upload_field').show()
  } else if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $('.upload_field').hide()
    $('.from_date, .to_date').show()
  } else {
    $('.upload_field').hide()
    $('.from_date, .to_date').hide()
  }
})
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
//hide on load
$('.from_date, .to_date').hide()
$('.upload_field').hide()

//watch the change
$(document).on('change', '#raise_invoice_raised_invoice_type', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '0') {
    $('.from_date, .to_date').hide()
    $('.upload_field').show()
  } else if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $('.upload_field').hide()
    $('.from_date, .to_date').show()
  } else {
    $('.upload_field').hide()
    $('.from_date, .to_date').hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="raise-invoice-form-validation" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="field columns large-3">
      <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_invoice_type">Invoice type</label>
      <select name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_type]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_type">
        <option value="" selected>Select One</option>
        <option value="0">services</option>
        <option value="1">milestones</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="field columns large-3 from_date">
      <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_from_date">From date</label>
      <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" name="raise_invoice[from_date]" id="raise_invoice_from_date"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button>
    </div>

    <div class="field columns large-3 to_date">
      <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_to_date">To date</label>
      <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" name="raise_invoice[to_date]" id="raise_invoice_to_date"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button>
    </div>

    <input value="20" type="hidden" name="raise_invoice[payment_milestone_id]" id="raise_invoice_payment_milestone_id">

    <div class="field columns large-2 upload_field">
      <label for="raise_invoice_upload_file">Upload file</label>
      <input type="file" name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_file]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_file">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="field columns large-3">
      <label for="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_for">Raised invoice for</label>
      <select name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_for]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_for">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="0">Performa Invoice</option>
        <option value="1">Tax Invoice</option>
      </select>

      <div class="actions text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Raise invoice" class="button primary button-margin-top" data-disable-with="Raise invoice">
      </div>

</form>
```

Comment: this code only works on first time each selection, also i want to hide from_date, to_date and upload file when invoice_type is not selected

Comment: @rock I have edited my answer - check my recent edit - all working i knew you would want something like that :)

Comment: can i hide input's from_date, to_date and upload_file when invoice_type is select one

Comment: @rock Yes all done. Check my answer again. I read your comment later.

Comment: On load i it's not hiding these three input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle(boolean)` and use selected value comparison to create the boolean

```js
$('#raise_invoice_raised_invoice_type').change(function() {
  const val = $(this).val();
  $('.from_date, .to_date').toggle(val === '0')
  $('.upload_field').toggle(val === '1');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="raise-invoice-form-validation" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="field columns large-3">
      <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_invoice_type">Invoice type</label>
      <select name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_type]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_type">
        <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
        <option value="0">services</option>
        <option value="1">milestones</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="field columns large-3 from_date">
      <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_from_date">From date</label>
      <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" name="raise_invoice[from_date]" id="raise_invoice_from_date"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button>
    </div>

    <div class="field columns large-3 to_date">
      <label class="required" for="raise_invoice_to_date">To date</label>
      <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" name="raise_invoice[to_date]" id="raise_invoice_to_date"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button>
    </div>

    <input value="20" type="hidden" name="raise_invoice[payment_milestone_id]" id="raise_invoice_payment_milestone_id">

    <div class="field columns large-2 upload_field">
      <label for="raise_invoice_upload_file">Upload file</label>
      <input type="file" name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_file]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_file">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="field columns large-3">
      <label for="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_for">Raised invoice for</label>
      <select name="raise_invoice[raised_invoice_for]" id="raise_invoice_raised_invoice_for">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="0">Performa Invoice</option>
        <option value="1">Tax Invoice</option>
      </select>

      <div class="actions text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Raise invoice" class="button primary button-margin-top" data-disable-with="Raise invoice">
      </div>

</form>
```